# Mongodb - moving a field in an array to a new array in another parent

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have the following data scheme in mongodb database.
Due to a user interaction an entry can be moved from CAT_A to CAT_B, and the angularjs model changes appropriately.

```
[
   {
      "_id":"537f4407cb8a077d396bd73e",
      "cat":"CAT_A",
      "ntype":"category",
      "entries":[
         {
            "title":"111",
            "content":"Content One",
            "ntype":"entry",
            "_id":"537f4407cb8a077d396bd741"
         },
         {
            "title":"222",
            "content":"Content Two",
            "ntype":"entry",
            "_id":"537f4407cb8a077d396bd740"
         },
         {
            "title":"333",
            "content":"Content Three",
            "ntype":"entry",
            "_id":"537f4407cb8a077d396bd73f"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"537f4407cb8a077d396bd742",
      "cat":"CAT_B",
      "ntype":"category",
      "entries":[
         {
            "title":"444",
            "content":"Content Four",
            "ntype":"entry",
            "_id":"537f4407cb8a077d396bd745"
         },
         {
            "title":"555",
            "content":"Content Five",
            "ntype":"entry",
            "_id":"537f4407cb8a077d396bd744"
         },
         {
            "title":"666",
            "content":"Content Six",
            "ntype":"entry",
            "_id":"537f4407cb8a077d396bd743"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How do I save this new model to the mongo database, or really what is the best way to handle this?
Things I've though about doing:

1. Simply remove all the categories involved(there will be more than 2) from the database, and recreate them from the new model. This seems inefficient, also the content field may contain larger amounts of data, which makes http requests expensive.
2. Same as 1, but leave the 'content' out of the schema, create a new collection for content only, and somehow link that to the entry ID.
3. Pull an entry from CAT_A and push to CAT_B, have struggled getting this working and what if I wanted to keep the index position as in the model? ie if I wanted to move entry 6 in CAT_B to between entry 1 and 2 in CAT_A?

cheers

EDIT new schemas:

```
var CatSchema = new Schema({
  name    : String,
  ntype   : String,
  incentries: {
    ntype   : String,
    entry_id : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Entry' },
    entry_title : String
    }
  });


var EntrySchema = new Schema({
  cat : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Cat' },
  title : String,
  content : String,
});
```

and the code:

```
exports.editCat = function (req, res) {
Cat.update({_id: req.body.old}, 
    {$pull: {'incentries': {'entry_id': req.body.entry}}}, 
    function (err, data) {
    });
Cat.update({_id: req.body.new}, 
    {$addToSet: { incentries : {'entry_id': req.body.entry, 'entry_title': req.body.entryTitle, ntype: 'entry' }}},
    function (err, data) {
    });
};
```

Comment: I see two completely different entries here and have read your question three times and I have no idea what you are talking about or what you intend to do.

Comment: @brenit0 did my answer helped you? you have any comments?

Comment: Put me on the right track, however I could not get it working like I wanted in the ui treeview menu I'm trying to implement. I have changed the schema, and split them up, and it is working as it should however, it needs 2 mongo operations, and probably not the most elegant way of doing it..

Comment: You can use $pull and $addToSet in the same operation ```cat.update({_id..}.{$pull:{...},$addToSet:{...}})```so the update operation is atomic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $pull and $push:

```
>db.elements.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537f6ddcd66d3634fe5963f6"),
    "arr" : [
        {
            "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd73e",
            "cat" : "CAT_A",
            "ntype" : "category",
            "entries" : [
                {
                    "title" : "111",
                    "content" : "Content One",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd741"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "222",
                    "content" : "Content Two",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd740"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "333",
                    "content" : "Content Three",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd73f"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd742",
            "cat" : "CAT_B",
            "ntype" : "category",
            "entries" : [
                {
                    "title" : "444",
                    "content" : "Content Four",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd745"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "555",
                    "content" : "Content Five",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd744"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "666",
                    "content" : "Content Six",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd743"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
> db.elements.update({"_id" : ObjectId("537f6ddcd66d3634fe5963f6")},{$pull:{"arr.0.entries":entry},$push:{"arr.1.entries":entry}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

>db.elements.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537f6ddcd66d3634fe5963f6"),
    "arr" : [
        {
            "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd73e",
            "cat" : "CAT_A",
            "ntype" : "category",
            "entries" : [
                {
                    "title" : "222",
                    "content" : "Content Two",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd740"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "333",
                    "content" : "Content Three",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd73f"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd742",
            "cat" : "CAT_B",
            "ntype" : "category",
            "entries" : [
                {
                    "title" : "444",
                    "content" : "Content Four",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd745"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "555",
                    "content" : "Content Five",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd744"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "666",
                    "content" : "Content Six",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd743"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "111",
                    "content" : "Content One",
                    "ntype" : "entry",
                    "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd741"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But you will have to know where CAT_A and CAT_B are within the array (position 0 and position 1)

You could also try a schema like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("537f6dddd66d3634fe5963f7"),
  "categories" : {
    CAT_A: {
      "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd73e",
      "cat" : "CAT_A",
      "ntype" : "category",
      "entries" : [...]
    },
    CAT_B:{
      "_id" : "537f4407cb8a077d396bd742",
      "cat" : "CAT_B",
      "ntype" : "category",
      "entries" : [...]
    }
  }
}
```

So you update query would finally be:

```
> db.elements.update({"_id" : ObjectId("537f6ddcd66d3634fe5963f6")},{$pull:{"categories.CAT_B.entries":entry},$push:{"categories.CAT_A.entries":entry}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

As long as you "cat" field is unique within a single document this other approach seems better to me.